# Why use the same paint instance for drawing two different width and height of the bitmap in onDraw() method.The paint looks different

Tags: android

I have two bitmap will to drawing on canvas.Drawing the first and secode I used the same Paint .The Paint strokeWidth is 6. But they are looks different. Is the paint will be sacled?Perhaps the bigger bitmap paint strokeWidth will be sacle to large?I'm not sure.